# PayPal IPNs sent to old URL

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using IPN to be notified of new payments from PayPal on my site. I have changed the URL address of the listener page, but after several hours messages for new orders are still being sent to the old URL. I even totally disabled IPNs and re-enabled them, still old URL is used. Is there something I can do, will it eventually resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `notify_url` is specified in the set up of each transaction, that URL will be used. This always takes precedence over any account-level IPN URL setting.

So, most likely you need to update/change your integration to pass the new desired `notify_url` when sending over each transaction (form post or SetExpressCheckout API call, typically)

---

Notifications for events on previous transactions, such as refunds or transactions for subscriptions created with the old notify_url , will still go to that old url. This can't be changed.

Comment: I did not use it (and still don't), but probably that is a way to go.

As an update, the new URL started working on the next day.